# How to compute confidence interval of the fitted value via nls()

Tags: r, nls

My data consist of two columns - time and cumulative number like below:

```
time <- c(1:14)
cum.num <- c(20, 45, 99, 195, 301, 407, 501, 582, 679, 753, 790, 861, 1011, 1441)
```

My non linear function is:

```
B/(B*C*exp(-A*B*time) + 1)
```

My objective is to model my data using non linear regression using `nls()` and to find confidence interval of the fitted value. I have tried the following

```
m1 <- nls(cum.num ~ B/((B*C)*exp(-A*B*time) + 1),start=list(A=0.001,B=1000,C=0.5))
```

I tried the following to compute the fitted value of my model:

```
predict(m1,interval="predict")
```

I got only the fitted value without lower and upper confidence interval:

```
[1]  116.9912  145.7954  181.1951  224.4367  276.8663  339.8665  414.7550
[8]  502.6399  604.2369  719.6632  848.2417  988.3638 1137.4632 1292.1377
```

My questions are:

a) Is there any way can I  compute lower and upper bound for the fitted values ? (Normally `lm()` function produce fitted value, lower, and upper bound by default)

b) Suppose I have new  time like:

```
new.time<-c(15:20)
```

Can I compute the predicted value of `cum.num` at `new.time` along with lower and upper bound?

Thank You so much for your HELP!!!!

Comment: Please format your question properly.

Comment: In nls() function it should be cum.num not cum.vul

Comment: typically `predict()` will accept the interval argument, which you would want to set as "confidence" but the help page `?predict.nls` tells us "this argument is ignored" so you can't do what you want, at least with`stats::predict()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your example, it seems that the model doesn't fit the data quite well, and the sample size is quite small. Normally, this means something going wrong, and you should modify your model before you doing any further analysis. But I still provide some way to calculate "confidence interval" through bootstrap method, although it may not be valid in this case.

These are the data we need:

```
time <- c(1:14)
cum.num <- c(20, 45, 99, 195, 301, 407, 501, 582, 679, 753, 790, 861, 1011, 1441)
new.time <- c(15:20)
all.time <- c(time, new.time)
```

We may give them other names, which are helpful for more general usage:

```
y=cum.num # the dependent variable values from data
x=time # the independent variable values from data
new.x=all.time # the independent variable values over which we want to predict
```

Here is the non-linear least-squares model used in this case, which is to be used in the equation but to be modified for use in the general case:

```
nls(y ~ B/((B*C)*exp(-A*B*x) + 1), start=list(A=0.001,B=1000,C=0.5),
    control = nls.control(maxiter = 500, warnOnly = TRUE))
```

Based on the model, we can define an `estimate` function to use to generate a vector of fitted values and predictions for each random generated index. The argument to the function should be some sample index, and in the function, a model based on the sample with the input index is fitted, and from the fitted model, a vector of fitted values and predictions are generated (since in the question a CI of fitted values and predictions are wanted).

```
estimate <- function(ind){
    x <- x[ind]
    y <- y[ind]
    m1 <- nls(y ~ B/((B*C)*exp(-A*B*x) + 1), start=list(A=0.001,B=1000,C=0.5),
          control = nls.control(maxiter = 500, warnOnly = TRUE))
    predict(m1, newdata = list(x = new.x))
}


m1 <- nls(cum.num ~ B/((B*C)*exp(-A*B*time) + 1),start=list(A=0.001,B=1000,C=0.5))
predict0 <- predict(m1, newdata = list(time = all.time))
predict1 <- replicate(1000, estimate(sample.int(14, replace = TRUE)))
intervals <- apply(predict1, 1, quantile, probs = c(0.05, 0.95))
rbind(predict0, intervals)
```

`predict1` is a matrix to store the bootstrap result. 
Each bootstrap sample has the same size with the original sample (14 in this example), and the bootstrap sample is generated from the original sample with simple random sampling with replacement. So `sample.int(14, replace = TRUE))` is used to generate the index for the bootstrap samples. And the `estimate` function is used to generate a vector of fitted values and predictions for each random generated index.

Since `predict1` is the bootstrapped fitted values and predictions, I calculate the 90% CI from the bootstrapped estimations. In the bootstrap procedure, there are a lot of warnings from `nls` function, which implies something wrong numerically, this is in accordance with the little sample size and the lack-of-fit model. And the final results looks like this:

```
> rbind(predict0, intervals)
[,1]      [,2]     [,3]     [,4]     [,5]     [,6]     [,7]     [,8]     [,9]
predict0 116.99118 145.79538 181.1951 224.4367 276.8663 339.8665 414.7550 502.6399 604.2369
5%        39.22272  67.34464 111.2190 173.7619 231.7736 289.7346 358.8469 436.2569 524.8187
95%      162.92948 190.60295 224.2462 266.1298 314.1032 392.3228 504.1270 611.3698 704.2803
[,10]    [,11]     [,12]     [,13]     [,14]     [,15]     [,16]     [,17]    [,18]
predict0 719.6632 848.2417  988.3638 1137.4632 1292.1377 1448.4271 1602.2033 1749.5981 1887.374
5%       627.1981 739.8984  822.7940  838.2366  846.9043  851.8955  854.2859  855.8558  856.873
95%      799.1904 923.1220 1068.4667 1231.6091 1416.4405 1631.2212 1900.6581 2220.5415 2617.839
[,19]     [,20]
predict0 2013.1701 2125.5890
5%        857.4619  857.8027
95%      3072.8531 3594.9036
>
```

Edit: Make some edits to improve the readability and to illustrate how to use the code for general usage based on @user3386170 's suggestion.

Comment: Thank YOU ...so much ..@Consistency

Comment: I *think* your answer is helpful and accurate... but I can't wrap my mind around how to write your function to match my data. Is there a way you could write it in a more general form? Or explain the terms? I don't want to ask a new question because I think your answer to close to what I need.

Comment: @user3386170 I'm glad the answer is helpful. I add more explanation in the answer to try to illustrate the basic idea of the bootstrap approach.

Comment: Thanks for your additional information. I've reworked it and managed to make it work with my data. I've written a general case equation as a separate answer with some extra explanations that you could use to replace some of your code if you think it is correct. I didn't want to edit your answer directly since the changes are so substantial.

Comment: What is the point of sampling two values twice in the bootstrap?  I'm not familiar with bootstrap methods, but would it be cleaner to sample some percentage of the data (e.g. 10-12 of the 14 values) only once (without replacement)?

Comment: @user3386170 If draw sample without replacement, then the percentage can't be too high, as the percentage is higher, the correlation between each sample is higher. The exact same problem is also in bootstrap method, but not so severe because of draw with replacement.

Comment: @user3386170  If the percentage is moderate, like 50%. Then the sample size of the new "bootstrap" sample is quite significant smaller than the sample size of the original one. This is important because the sample size matters a lot for the confidence interval. If you just sample a 50% percentage of the data, your confidence interval will generally be wider. If having a wider confidence interval is okay, then nothing is wrong with just draw a moderate percentage (like 50% or 60%) of the sample without replacement.

Comment: @user3386170 Thank you for your suggestion. Answer improved based on your suggestion.